# NumbaPro on Cuda device over ssh connection

Tags: python, ssh, cuda, numba-pro

I'm using Python/NumbaPro to use my CUDA complient GPU on a windows box. I use Cygwin as shell and from within a cygwin console it has no problems finding my CUDA device. I test with the simple command

```
    numbapro.check_cuda()
```

But when I'm connection to the box over OpenSSH (as part of my Cygwin setup), I get the following error:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError: Error at driver init:
Call to cuInit results in CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE:
```

How to fix this?

Comment: is sshd running as a service, if so, that is your problem

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the sshd context from windows service to command line, now running in the same user context as my other user. This results in a new error: "raise NotImplementedError('cannot determine number of cpus')" - why can that be?

Comment: That isn't really anything to do with CUDA, but I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13544826/681865) probably answers that question (see the last answer).

Comment: I'll add a short summary answer to the question if you will accept it so we can get this off the unanswered list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary cause of this is Windows service session 0 isolation. When you run any application via a service which runs in session 0 (so sshd, or windows remote desktop, for example), the machines native display driver is unavailable. For CUDA applications, this means that you are get a no device available error at runtime because the sshd you use to login is running as a service and there is no available CUDA driver.

The are a few workarounds:

1. Run the sshd as a process rather than a service.
2. If you have a compatible GPU, use the TCC driver rather than the GPU display driver.

On the secondary problem, the Python runtime error you are seeing comes from the `multiprocessing` module. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13544826/681865) it appears that the root cause is probably the `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` environment variable not being set. You can use one of the workarounds in that thread to get around that problem

Comment: I think it would be interesting to test whether this (session 0 isolation limitation) is still true with a very recent NVIDIA windows driver, such as 353.30.  NVIDIA has worked around some of these limitations.